# I need to convert linear comma separated data to columns in excel

Tags: database, excel, data-conversion

I need to convert linear comma separated data to columns in excel. For example:

86401, 86403, 86404, 86406, 86409, 86413, 86426, 86429, 86436, 86438, 86440, 86442

Is there a formula I can run to get the result below? I need this data to populate in a column in excel.

86401
86403
86404
86406
86409
86413
86426
86429
86436
86438
86440
86442

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Text to Columns with `,` as delimiter then Transpose should work.

Answer (score 0):

You can adjust this to meed your needs:

```
Sub Columate()
    ary = Split(ActiveCell.Value, ",")
    Dim Destination As Range
    Set Destination = Range("B9")
    For i = LBound(ary) To UBound(ary)
        Destination(i) = ary(i)
    Next i
End Sub
```

It take the contents of the ActiveCell, splits it, and stores the results downward starting at cell B9